# Stopping script mid execution on exit

Tags: php

On a user action I am running a back end system script through an AJAX call which does not output until it is complete. The issue is that a user could easily waste resources by starting the script then leaving the page. The goal is to break out of a while loop on exit.

To start, I made it add a file to the cache when it starts and I check it on every iteration. That works correctly because if I change the file value through another AJAX call, it will exit.

So my question is, how can I break out of that loop when you leave the page?

My only guess is to do a JS onunload AJAX call to alter the cache file, but that's a poor and highly unreliable approach for obvious reasons. Thanks

**//Edit//**

So I have given connection_aborted a ignore_user_abort a shot. Here is a very watered down version of the code.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$handle=opendir($dir);
if($handle)
{
    while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))&&!connection_aborted())
    {
       sleep(1);
       unlink($dir."/".$file);
    }
}
```

So even after I leave the page, the files are still being removed from the folder. My goal is to get out of that loop and stop all unlinking if you leave the page.

Comment: what about: http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Comment: Code would be lovely. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I added some code on what I've tried as far as connection_aborted() goes

Answer (score 0):

You can check for [`connection_aborted()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)

Answer (score 0):

> On a user action I am running a back end system script through an AJAX
>   call which does not output until it is complete. The issue is that a
>   user could easily waste resources by starting the script then leaving
>   the page. The goal is to break out of a while loop on exit.

You should check out:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Sounds like they can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added some code on what I've tried regarding those functions.